# I don't understand the variable let number= 0

Tags: javascript, variables

I don't understand what's the use of let number= 0. Without it, the code still works

```js
const countLetter = (sentence) => {

let number = 0;
for (const letter in sentence){
number = Number(letter)
}
return { number }
}

console.log(countLetter('the best day'))
```

I don't understant the purpose of let number = 0

Comment: There is no point to that initialization. Also, there is really no point to the entire function. Where did you find this? It absolutely will not count the number of letters in the sentence. *edit* well sometimes it's OK to be wrong :)

Comment: Why do you use a loop? You return the last character. The code also works without the loop: `const number = Number(sentence[sentence.length - 1]);`

Comment: @jabaa it's a `for ... in` loop. The values are the keys, so the last key is the length (minus 1)!

Comment: @Pointy Yes, you're right. It's `const number = Math.max(0, sentence.length - 1);`

Comment: Look this question is not really useful to anybody, it's weird and bad code, and while it almost works (it's off-by-1 if you really want the length) the point of the code is unclear and that's a silly way of computing that value. Without context of where that code was found, it's unlikely to do anybody any good. It's probably a dup of one of the "why does `for ... in` do something weird" questions.

Comment: You need `let number = 0;` for `console.log(countLetter(''))`. In that case the loop doesn't work.

Comment: @jabaa I concede. Why have I been thinking about this for so long.

Comment: Normally a function that counts something needs to initialize the counter to 0, then in the loop it adds 1 to the counter whenver the condition that it's counting is met. The problem with this code is that it never checks a condition, so it's not actually counting anything.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the initialization

```
let number = 0
```

is so that, if passed an empty string, `countLetter` returns `{number: 0}` instead of `{number: undefined}`.

This is not to say that the function posted makes any particular sense. Although not the question asked, changing the for loop to a `for...of` construct would at least process individual letters instead of their index in the string, but the purpose of the loop remains unclear.